# Linux set time from net at login

Tags: cron, sudo

On my Ubuntu 10.04 box I (a user, not root) can issue

```
sudo net time set
```

and it works great.

I'd prefer that the box get the net time on a more regular basis, or at least each time it gets logged in.  So, I tried adding **net time set** to */etc/profile*.  That fails.  I added stanzas that look like

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/net
```

to */etc/sudoers* (using **visudo**).  Didn't help.

I have never touched **cron** so I have no idea how to add a chron tab.  (does seem oxymoronic to depend on the system time to reset the system time.)

1. What is the best way to do this?
2. If it's a cron job, I'd appreciate a quick example.
3. Same questions but for the command **service dhcp3-server restart**?

(yes, my box gets its address by dhcp, but its dhcp server controls 4 gigabit enet cards attached to high speed cameras.  Sometimes, at login? bootup? the dhcp server leaves me seeing only 1 camera.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Yes, I'm adding a second answer.)

From your description, you've added the appropriate line to `/etc/sudoers`, but you're not invoking `sudo` in `/etc/profile`.

The command in `/etc/profile` needs to be:

```
sudo net time set
```

Note that this will run every time any account logs in.  Is that what you want, or would it make more sense to put the command in `$HOME/.profile`?

To make it a cron job, you can add something like this:

```
0 * * * * *      sudo net time set
```

to, say, `foo.txt`, then `crontab foo.txt`.  After that, `crontab -l` will show you your current cron job(s).  With the given parameters, the job will run once an hour; `man 5 crontab` and adjust as needed.  There *might* be some issues because cron jobs run with a minimal environment, but I don't think `/usr/bin/net` depends on any environment variables.

Note that, unlike `ntpd`, this can cause your system's clock to jump backwards, which can cause problems.

Comment: Finally, I have an NTP server address I can use!  So, can you give me a bit of guidance on NTPD?  Thank you Keith!

Comment: @WesMiller: I've updated my other answer, which now seems to be the more relevant one.

Comment: @WesMiller: Isn't my other answer the actual solution that you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.

The usual way to keep the system clock synchronized is `ntpd`. It should be installed and configured by default on Ubuntu. Do you have an `ntpd` process running? Is your system's clock incorrect?

**EDIT :**

From your comment on my other answer, it looks like you've got an NTP server you can use.

You should already have the `ntp` software installed on your system.  `dpkg -l ntp` to verify.  You probably have an `ntpd` daemon already running, though it won't work because it doesn't know what server to talk to; `ps -ef | grep ntpd` to confirm that.

`/etc/ntp.conf` is the configuration file for ntp.  The default version has:

```
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
```

Comment out those lines and add:

```
server your.ntp.server
```

then run:

```
sudo /etc/init.d ntp restart
```

`man ntpd` for more details, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: My system clock was incorrect.  Running a **net time set** once seemed to fix it.  Interestingly enough, the man for **net** says I have to identify the ntp server.  I didn't, but it still seemed to work.  Wonder why.  Anyway, apparently ntpd is not on my machine and is not running.  I'm in my clients VPN and can't connect out of it to anyuthing but my remote desktop.  Unless I can get a package that I can **cp** onto the machine, I'm out of luck.

Comment: Ok, then if you can't connect to anything but your remote desktop then `ntpd` isn't going to be able to talk to an NTP server, unless you can set up such a server on your remote desktop.  (`ntpd` is the right solution for most circumstances, though.)